# What does "No the now" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In [Braveheart (1995)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braveheart), William Wallace wants Murron to ridee with him but her parents
won't approve:

> William Wallace: It's good Scottish weather, madam. The rain is
> falling straight  down. Slightly to the side, like.
>
> Mother: She can't go with you.
>
> William Wallace: No?
>
> Mother: **No the now**, anyway.

What does "No the now" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No the now" is *Scottish English dialect* and should be understood to mean "not just now", or "not right now". "*The now*" is perhaps one of the most widely known *Scotticisms* (at least among British English speakers).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotticism) notes that "*an archetypal example of an overt Scotticism is 'Och aye the noo', which translates as 'Oh yes, just now'"*. Although these days, this precise phrase is more of a *stereotype* than an archetype, and not likely to be said by a Scot.

Comment: Note that 'noo' is the [correct spelling](https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/noo) of the Scots word.